# How should one cope with multiple delegates in a paged UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView, contains 3 pages.

The first two are `UITableView`, the third one is a `UICollectionView`

So in one View Controller I will have to write delegate methods for all of them.

I googled a bit and found a solution like this (not tested yet),

> Place each page in a separate UIViewController, implement the
>   corresponding delegate methods, and use `UIViewController.view`
>   attribute to build the scroll view

The `UIViewController.view` approach seems wrong to me, is that the normal way to do it?

Comment: set outlets to each tableview and collectionview and check it in delegates.
I mean `if(tableview == yourtableview)` in datasource or delegates.

Comment: @sohanvanani I'm trying to place the delegate methods in different files, and different view controllers

Comment: ok i think this will be easy see my edited comment

Comment: @sohanvanani Thanks .. but I don't quite get it ... I have both table view and uicollectionview

Comment: see for tableview just you can return cell as per which tableview datasource called you can check this in cellforrowatindexpath.

Comment: Why are you trying to handle all the delegate calls in one view controller, can't you create separate view controller for each of them? If you are not separating now then it will be tougher for you to handle all in one file.

Comment: The answer you found is correct.  PageVC pages are view controllers (not views).  Make each view controller be a delegate for the type of view it holds.

Comment: If it helps, please accept the answer else give more details, I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to handle all the delegate calls in one view controller, can't you create separate view controller for each of them? If you are not separating now then it will be tougher for you to manage code later.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely using controller composition is a standard and respected solution to the Massive View Controller problem. Examine for instance the expositions at [the StackViewController project](https://github.com/seedco/StackViewController) which cleverly uses that concept to create forms in a UIStackView:

> Composition over inheritance is a fundamental principle of object-oriented programming.
>
> This principle has always been used in iOS view hierarchies, where more complex views are composed out of simpler ones (e.g. how a UIButton contains a UILabel and a UIImageView that render its content). However, there was no "official" way to compose view controllers until the introduction of view controller containment in iOS 5. It was possible to mimic behaviour like this prior to iOS 5, but handling the propagation of events between parent and child view controllers and transitions between child view controllers was difficult to get right, which are all problems that the view controller containment API solves.
>
> In the same way that you can create complex layouts by composing multiple UIStackView instances, you can use the view controller containment API to compose multiple instances of StackViewController to create a hierarchy of view controllers where each content view is backed by a corresponding view controller that cleanly separates the responsibilities, instead of handling all of that at the view level (an anti-pattern, as mentioned earlier).

Also review [8 Patterns to Help You Destroy Massive View Controller](http://khanlou.com/2014/09/8-patterns-to-help-you-destroy-massive-view-controller/), particularly

> Standard Composition
>
> View controllers can be composed using the View Controller Containment APIs introduced in iOS 5. If your view controller is composed of several logical units that could each be their own view controller, consider using Composition to break them apart. A practical application of this litmus test is a screen with multiple table views or collection views.

Which is, in fact, the exact situation that you have to practically apply it to!